# Is this currect way to define Junit version in pom.xml?

Tags: java, junit, pom.xml

Actually, am learning Spring MVC, I have some doubt in defining version values in the pom.xml file I have seen in a forum to define Junit version values like this  `<version>${junit.version}</version>` is this correct format?

Comment: Hi. Have you tried `**${junit.version}`? If so, is it working? I would suggest you to check the [how to ask help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve the quality of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use inline versions:

```
<dependency>  
  <groupId>junit</groupId>  
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>  
  <version>4.8.2</version>  
  <scope>test</scope> 
</dependency>
```

or properties:

```
<project>
...
  <properties>
     <junit.version>4.8.2</junit.version>
  </properties>
...
</project>
```

Use this property in `<dependency>`

```
<dependency>  
  <groupId>junit</groupId>  
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>  
  <version>${junit.version}</version>  
  <scope>test</scope> 
</dependency>
```